# VS shows References that are not in csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-edge, csproj, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to compile WebView for embedding Edge in WPF (Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView). Its available on Git at https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit

The csproj has no reference to "Windows", but Visual Studio shows that its a missing reference. not sure how to resolve this. any help is appreciated. I get an error when removing "Windows" Reference - "Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference was getting added from Directory.Build.targets file. it had the following condition that was adding the reference

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(IsWin32Project)' == 'true' or '$(IsWpfProject)' == 'true' or '$(IsFormsProject)' == 'true'">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == ''">10.0.$(DefaultTargetPlatformVersion).0</TargetPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="'$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)' == ''">10.0.$(DefaultTargetPlatformMinVersion).0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Windows">
          <HintPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)\Windows.winmd')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
          <HintPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\Windows.winmd')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the reference and then remove it. Once it's done you can then go to Build and then clean, then rebuild the solution.

Comment: that does not work in this case. I will update the question to clarify that

Comment: @Dhawalk have you tried to delete the `obj` `bin` and hidden `.vs` folder in your project path?

Comment: yes, I have. To clarify, I understand the structure and nuances of Visual Studio and csproj files.  this is the first time I am seeing a reference that is not listed in csproj. I am sure there is something new I will learn here. thanks for the help man

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to compile WebView for embedding Edge in WPF

Please refer to the following article to install the Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView package and using the WebView control in a WPF application.

[WebView control for Windows Forms and WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#about-webview-controls)

Comment: I did, and it has a check for OS version level. I wanted to change it in the source and see if it ran on my machine without having to update my OS. that was the reason, why i wanted to build the WebView source code. in any case, i was able to build it. see my answer below